# React UseEffect Function Not Performing Properly

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, mapbox, use-effect, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to get a box to appear on a MapboxGL application. Most of the application is built using React. I only want useEffect() to be called once, so I added [] as a second parameter at the end of the function per the suggestion of other questions on this forum. Unfortunately, the box no longer shows up on the map, so it seems that the function is no longer being called and it is always defaulting to the second parameter. Why is this happening and what can I do to mend this issue?

```
  React.useEffect(() => {

    if(props.show) {
      console.log(props);
      var northEast = [131.308594, 46.195042];
      var southEast = [117.597656, 8.233237];
      var southWest = [79.101563, 32.842674];
      var northWest = [86.847656, 44.715514];

      // Add bounding box to the map
      // Defines bounding box
      globalMap.addSource('newroute', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {},
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [
                    northEast, southEast, southWest, northWest, northEast
                ]
            }
        }
      });

      // Draws bounding box
      globalMap.addLayer({
        'id': 'newroute',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'newroute',
        'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#ff0000',
            'line-width': 5
        }
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is props.show true?  Do you get the console message?  Do you get a message if you put the console outside of the if condition?

Comment: @tarmes for a reason unknown to me, adding the second parameter makes the prop be false

Comment: We need more code

Comment: where is the props coming from ? is there a chance that your props.show will change from false to true ? . If yes the you need to add that as a dependency to your useEffect .

Comment: @Shyam it is coming from a search form. When the search button is pressed, I want it to trigger the useEffect function.

Comment: will the search button changes the value of show from false to true ?